# 計数ソートを入力順にソートした際の安定性

Tags: c, アルゴリズム, データ構造

下の疑似コードで実装された計数ソート(Counting Sort)の探索を現在と逆順にした場合、安定したソートを保持したままにするにはどの方法が効率がいいでしょうか？
事実、このアルゴリズムでは入力配列を後ろからソートしないと、同じ要素が現れた場合その要素の順番は逆になってしまい、安定したソートではなくなります。
私は。同じ要素が複数回出現した場合に限り、その要素数-1をしたものをそれぞれのカウンターから引けばいいと思ったのですが、その場合はもう一つ余計な配列を用意しなければならず、非効率的ではないかと指摘されました。しかし、それ以外の方法が思いつきません。
なにか手法などありましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

pseudo-code (reference: Algorithm Introduction, MIT Press)

```
COUNTING-SORT(A,B,k) 
C[0..k] を新しい配列とする 
for i = 0 to k 
    C[i] = 0 
for j = 1 to A.length 
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1 
    //C[i] は i と等しい要素の数を示す． 
for i = 1 to k 
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i−1] 
    //C[i] は i 以下の要素の数を示す． 
for j = A.length downto 1 
    B[C[A[j]]] = A[j]
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]]−1
```

このアルゴリズムの最後のforループを、for (j = 1 to A.length) にしたいです

Comment: `B[C[A[j]]] = A[j] 12 C[A[j]] = C[A[j]]−1`の`12`は何を意味していますか？

Comment: 12 については、おそらくコピー＆ペーストの際に行番号が入って改行が入らなかったのだと推測し、そのように修正しておきました。もしそうでなければ再度修正をお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

このアルゴリズムでは最後のループが回る直前の `C[i]` の値が、配列 `B` における値 `i` の**末尾**のインデックスを示すように計算されています。このため最後のループでは配列 `A` を**後ろ**から走査する形が自然です。

逆に考えると、最後のループで配列 `A` を**前**から走査したければ、`C[i]` の値が配列 `B` における値 `i` の**先頭**のインデックスを示すように計算すれば良いです。

これを計算するやり方はいくつかあると思いますが、たとえば以下のようにできます。

```
COUNTING-SORT(A, B, k)
C[0..(k + 1)] を新しい配列とする
for i = 0 to (k + 1)
    C[i] = 0
for j = 1 to A.length
    C[A[j] + 1] = C[A[j] + 1] + 1
    //C[i + 1] は i と等しい要素の数を示す．
for i = 1 to k
    C[i] = C[i] + C[i−1]
    //C[i] は i 未満の要素の数を示す (i ∈ {1..k})．
for j = 1 to A.length
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1
    B[C[A[j]]] = A[j]
```

Comment: 一番最後の`C[A[j]] = C[A[j]] + 1`は`B[C[A[j]]] = A[j]`の前に実行しないとbへの格納が 0-indexedになるようですがいかがでしょうか？間違っていたらごめんなさい。

Comment: 本当ですね。ありがとうございます、修正しました。

Answer (score -1):

**分布数え上げソートのC言語による実装**
　計数ソート(Counting Sort)を調べてみたところ、次のページが見つかりました。

- [分布数え上げソート [Counting Sort]](https://www.codereading.com/algo_and_ds/algo/counting_sort.html)
- [分布数え上げソートのデモンストレーション・プログラム: counting_sort.c](https://www.codereading.com/algo_and_ds/algo/source/counting_sort.c)

  質問された方の疑似コードとデモンストレーション・プログラムに以下の違いがあります。
- 疑似コード
  A と B は 1-indexed、C は 0-indexed
- デモンストレーション・プログラム
  C言語で実装しているため、A B Cはすべて0-indexed、ただしCは最初の要素を使用せず、 1-indexedのように使っています。　
  　このため疑似コードの(1)と(2)は、デモンストレーション・プログラムでは順序が逆になっています。

```
for j = A.length downto 1 
    B[C[A[j]]] = A[j]     ・・・・・（１）
    C[A[j]] = C[A[j]]−1 　・・・・・（２）
```

**入力配列を後ろからソートするアルゴリズム**
　nekketsuuu♦さんの回答(前から)とのアルゴリズムと質問された方のアルゴリズム(後ろから)の振る舞いを比較しました。双方とも安定なソートであることが確認できました。

比較にした入力データaは{8,4,10,3,8,5}です。
　双方のアルゴリズムとも`a[1]`の8が`b[4]`に格納され、`a[5]`の8が`b[5]`に格納されています。

【前から処理】

```
b[4] = a[1]:8
b[2] = a[2]:4
b[6] = a[3]:10
b[1] = a[4]:3
b[5] = a[5]:8
b[3] = a[6]:5
```

【後ろから処理】

```
b[3] = a[6]:5
b[5] = a[5]:8
b[1] = a[4]:3
b[6] = a[3]:10
b[2] = a[2]:4
b[4] = a[1]:8
```

---

**回答を大幅に修正しました。

　先の回答では質問された方の疑似コードに誤りがあると指摘しましたが誤解でした。

　大変失礼しました、お詫びいたします。**

Comment: 後ろから走査したときに安定なのはそうで、前から走査したときにも安定したままにするには、というご質問に読めます。

Comment: ご指摘のとおり、質問の趣旨を読み違えていました。

Comment: 今回の疑似コード、やや分かりにくいのですが `C` は 0-indexed なのに対し `A` と `B` は 1-indexed になっています。`C` は辞書であるが `A` と `B` は配列である、という風に理解すると自然な設定です。冒頭に書いてある動作不良についてはこれが原因ではないでしょうか？　つまり、疑似コードとしては間違っていないです。

Comment: ご指摘のとおりでした、疑似コードをそのままコードにしてみたところ正しくソートされていました。